# What does "imprecise" means in the description of std::map?

Tags: c++

In the description of std::map (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), it says:

> "Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)."

My question is: I think `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` is precise here, why the document says it is "imprecise"?

Comment: It is precise in that it lays out how the equivalence is implemented. It is imprecise in that it doesn't link the implementation `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` to the formal, declarative definition of the equivalence relation. I would read "imprecise terms" as "let's not do math, here's just what happens".

Comment: The phrase `"In imprecise terms"` is simply a term-of-art, or metaphor if you will, explaining that the discussion that follows will be using general terms where there may not be a one-to-one correlation between the terms used here and those used in the C/C++ standard.Essentially saying "this is the crux of the issue".

Comment: I might be off, but one way to read it is "In imprecise terms, [imprecise terms] : [more precise terms]". Note that the [named requirement Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) uses the same formulation of `equiv(a, b), an expression equivalent to !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` but thats not the only requirement.